# Implicit conversion where there resulting type is a type projection on a generic type

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, type-projection

I have some scala 2.13 code that basically boils down to this

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

trait Base {
  type V
  def v: V
}

case class Derived(v: Int) extends Base {
  type V = Int
}


object TestImplicitConversion {
  implicit def getV[T <: Base](a: T): T#V = a.v

  val a: Int = Derived(5)
}
```

Here I would expect the compiler to use the implicit conversion `getV` to convert `Derived` to `Int`, but the code does not compile. Manually adding the call to `getV`, will make the code compile. Can someone help me understand why the conversion where in the standard it is explained.

The way I found of making such a conversion work is by adding a second generic parameter and a constraint

```scala
implicit def getV2[T <: Base, S](a: T)(implicit constraint: T#V =:= S): S = constraint(a.v)
```

with this version the compiler uses the conversion and the code does compile.

**Edit:**

The alternative solution provided by @user using refinement type does indeed seem like a better approach. But it does not really provide an answer to why it original implementation does not work. So I am still interested in understanding why the compiler does not use the implicit def when an explicit call will make the code compile.

Comment: Just a hint, try to avoid using general type projection, it is [unsound](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1050), here there are some [examples](https://lptk.github.io/programming/2019/09/13/type-projection.html). [Scala 3](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/type-projection.html) drops general type projection. It is better to leverage path-dependent type, for example: `implicit def getV[T <: Base](a: T): a.V = a.v`

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi Replacing type projection `T#V` by path-dependent type `a.V` doesn't help. Scala 2.13.6.

Comment: @DmytroMitin It appears to [work](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nSgAZ4P5Rne5pJ3rTgXtOw) for me.

Comment: @user You removed `implicit`. Surely with explicit call it works.

Comment: @user If you remove `implicit` then there is no need to replace type projections with path-dependent types. Explicit call works even with type projection.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I didn't realize what the OP wanted it for, although it still [works](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ap4OzHIXSVKvCwjNzvnyxw) with implicits.

Comment: @user So it works in Scala 3.0.1 but doesn't in 2.13.6. Interesting. As you know `implicit` keyword is not forever in Scala 3. Try to implement this with `given`/`using`/`Conversion` ;)

Comment: @DmytroMitin Whoops, I didn't realize my Scastie was using Scala 3.

Comment: @user Well, you're using Scala 3 with Scala 2 implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

As gianluca aguzzi mentioned in the comments, type projection is unsound and should be avoided. Moreover, `T` is not a concrete type, so you can't use projections on it anyway. You can accept only `Base#V` as a type parameter instead, and use a refinement type for the type of `a`:

```scala
implicit def get[T](a: Base { type V = T }): T = a.v
```

Thus, you can avoid casting and type projections.

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Xp3oiTVfS0mBHDmdaXvxSg)

Comment: There is a hypothesis that type projections remain sound as long as they are not mixed with lower bounds/intersection types https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-feature-requests/issues/14 https://lptk.github.io/programming/2019/09/13/type-projection.html

Comment: I'm not sure about actual OP's needs but the original question was about implicit conversions.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Ah, that's very interesting! Let's hope that this is eventually implemented in Scala 3.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I've deleted the path-dependent type part and written a Scala 2-only answer (with a Scastie that uses Scala 2 instead of Scala 3), I'll add a Scala 3 one later.

Comment: This works in Scala 3 too: `given [T]: Conversion[Base { type V = T }, T] = _.v`

Comment: I think this approach provided here is better then what was used in the original question. But I would still like to understand why the original version does not work. Because adding the call explicitly in scala 2.13 will compile and work as expected.

Comment: @emilejby I'd expect that the compiler doesn't bother looking too closely at whether `T#V` could be an `Int` so as not to slow down implicit conversions too much. I think it only looks at `Base#V` and sees that it's not `Int`. Take that with a grain of salt, though, I don't have anything to support this.